# problems with drawImage when jar is executed

Tags: image, graphics, jar, drawimage

I want to use a buffered image as background for my frame. I use a mouselistener to detect when my mouse moves over a specific area to highlight a button but drawing an image over it (newgame.jpg or loadgame.jpg). It all works fine when I excecute it in ecplise, but when I create a Jar file my background won't load.
This is the code:

```
 in the constructor:
try {
            background = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Images/SMAGE_achtergrond.jpg"));
            newgame = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Images/newgame.jpg"));
            loadgame = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource("Images/loadgame.jpg"));                     
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
....
...
the next method is being called every 10ms (increasing it to 1 second 5 seconds doesn't make it work)

    public void refresh()
{              
    BufferedImage temp = new BufferedImage(800,400,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics g2 = temp.getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(background,0,0,null);
    if (newGame){
        g2.drawImage(newgame,36,282,null); 
    }
    if (loadGame)
    {
        g2.drawImage(loadgame, 37, 327, null);
    }        
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    g.drawImage(temp,0,0,null);            
}
```

There is a thread that repeatedly calls refresh().
Now here is the strange part:
When newGame/loadgame is true, g2.drawImage(newgame/loadgame,36,282,null); is executed correcly. But the rest of the method is always ignored. 
The path to all images is the same, and they're all in the same location so that isn't the problem.

And it only doesn't work when I put it in a jar file.

I've also tried to use this:

```
        background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Images/SMAGE_achtergrond.jpg"));
        newgame = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Images/newgame.jpg"));
        loadgame = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Images/loadgame.jpg"));
```

But it doesn't change anything.
I hope someone can tell me what's going wrong here.
Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a new buffered image every 10ms. You also don't dispose of the graphics object you create every 10ms either.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant to say that the refresh method is being called every 10 ms. The buffered images are only created once in the constructor.